# ListBox populated with DataSet doesn't update

Tags: c#, listbox, dataset

Second Version

I'm populating a `ListBox` using the following code

```
private BindingSource sri = new BindingSource();

public void sola()
{
    sri.DataSource = llenar.Tables["tipoender"];
    listBox1.DataSource = sri;
    listBox1.ValueMember = "end_tipoendereco";
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "tpl_descricao";
}
```

I use this to DELETE (updating with the value 2 a determined column), when the column ID_tipoauditoria value =2 the record is not loaded . This code is working

```
DataSet grava = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommandBuilder constru8 = new SqlCommandBuilder(da4);
SqlParameter codi = new SqlParameter("@emp", SqlDbType.Int);
codi.Value = codem;
SqlCommand llena10 = new SqlCommand("dmlpjende", conec1);
llena10.Parameters.Add(codi);
llena10.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da4.SelectCommand = llena10;
da4.Fill(grava, "endere");
DataRow dr2 = grava.Tables["endere"].Rows[ni];
// listBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
dr2.BeginEdit();
dr2["id_tipoauditoria"] = 2;
dr2.EndEdit();
da4.Update(grava.Tables["endere"]);
```

What is the best method to refresh the `ListBox`? I have tried resetting the binding with no-success. I only need to refresh the dataset or the listbox.

Comment: I do not really understand what do you mean but did you try `listBox1.Refresh();`? Have a great day :)

Comment: One thing to note here is that you're never actually changing the `llenar.Tables["tipoender"];` data -- so the combo box isn't going to change, even if `Refresh` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solve the problem of refresh the listbox, loading again the dataset,

```
    public void cargill()
    {
        campo = "60435351000319";
        llenar = ifd.consulta_cnpj(campo);
        sola();
    }

    public void sola()
    {
        sri.DataSource = llenar.Tables["tipoender"];
        listBox1.DataSource = sri;
        listBox1.ValueMember = "end_tipoendereco";
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "tpl_descricao";
    }

          DataSet grava = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommandBuilder constru8 = new SqlCommandBuilder(da4);
            SqlParameter codi = new SqlParameter("@emp", SqlDbType.Int);
            codi.Value = codem;
            SqlCommand llena10 = new SqlCommand("dmlpjende", conec1);
            llena10.Parameters.Add(codi);
            llena10.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da4.SelectCommand = llena10;
            da4.Fill(grava, "endere");
            DataRow dr2 = grava.Tables["endere"].Rows[ni];
            dr2.BeginEdit();
            dr2["id_tipoauditoria"] = 2;
            dr2.EndEdit();
            da4.Update(grava.Tables["endere"]);
            cargill();
```

I like use dispose and refresh but this way work.

Answer (score 0):

I might completely misunderstand your question, but this might work better:

```
public void sola()
{
    sri.DataSource = llenar.Tables["tipoender"];
    listBox1.DataSource = sri;
    listBox1.ValueMember = "end_tipoendereco";
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "tpl_descricao";
    listBox1.DataBind(); // this was missing
}
```

especially the last line I added, for actually data binding. Does this solve your problem? And if not, what happens if you call `listBox1.Refresh()` afterwards as suggested in the comments.